# Problem when trying to send many emails to one person from one IP

Tags: php, email, email-spam

I want to send emails to huge list for marketing purpose. 
now when i try to send many emails to one person but. 
now all my mails are going as spam. 
then i try to find some solution for that, then i came to know that. 
if i try to send lots of email to one person from one ip then they(email providers) take that as spam or in worst case they may block that ip address.

then i tried to find the solution, 
this is only assumption..
can i use proxy server to send my emails so that my ip address not be same so may be email provider don't make my ip as spam.
or is their solution?

**EDIT**: I had no intension to ask that "how to send spam", i had only asked bcz i have one project in that their is requirement like this...

Comment: Marketing purposes is often spam.

Comment: And that's a programming question how?

Comment: Your IP is probably blacklisted by one of the Relay Black Lists (RBL). It's probably for a reason. In any case, this question does not belong on Stack Overflow... it's not a programming question.

Comment: @user502515 - No, no, it's only spam when OTHER people are doing it :)

Comment: "now all my mails are going as spam." ... well, are they? Sounds like the mail client is doing its job well.

Comment: I really wonder what one would do with an app that sends thousands of emails behind a proxy.

Comment: i am working as freelancer so their is one project that came to my way in that this kind of specification was given, so i tried to check but i don't find any solution so i asked here. i thought their will any way....

Comment: You need to get hold of a zombie network or an open relay and get them to do your dirty work!!

Comment: Just because a lot of companies want to be able to do something doesn't mean they have a right to do it (especially when tools like spam filters exist specifically to *stop* them doing it)

Comment: "one project that came to my way in that this kind of specification was given".  You should have told them to stuff it.  Spam is evil.

Answer (score 2):

I agree your IP is probably blacklisted.  I suggest an email marketing service such as iContact or Campaign Monitor.